# Erro Call to a member function prepare

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A conexão com o banco esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas o metodo getList me retorna esse erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/config/config.class.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/config/config.class.php(43): Conexao->getList() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/config/config.class.php on line 32
```

eu entendi que esta na linha 32, mas não consigo encontrar nada de errado nessa linha, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda por favor? o código esta abaixo:

```
<?php 

class Conexao {

    private $sql,$user,$pass,$lista;

    public function __construct($sql = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste',$user = 'root', $pass = '') {

        $this->sql  = $sql;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;

    }

    public function Conecta(){

        try {

            new PDO($this->sql,$this->user,$this->pass);

        }catch(Exception $e) {

            var_dump($e);

        }

    }

    public function getList() {

        $this->lista = $this->Conecta()->prepare('SELECT * FROM outros');
        $this->lista->execute();
        $this->lista->fetchAll();

    }

}


$testando = new Conexao;
$testando->Conecta();
$testando->getList();
```

Comment: O método `Conecta` não deveria retornar a instância de PDO?

Comment: Como assim? desculpe mas não entendi

Comment: Dentro do método `getList` você acessa o método `prepare` do que retornar de `Conecta`, mas tal método retorna nada. Tente colocar: `return new PDO(...)`

Comment: deu certinho, muito obrigado, eu achava que o metodo try fazia o retorno de forma automatica, sem precisar mandar retornar algo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta um `return` dentro de `Conecta`, faça assim:

```
public function Conecta(){

    try {

        return new PDO($this->sql,$this->user,$this->pass);

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }

}
```

Se não o retorno será `null` e não terá como acessar os métodos de `new PDO`

Na verdade nem precisa chamar toda vez o Connecta, você poderia criar uma variavel para verificar se já instanciou a classe PDO, assim:

```
<?php 

class Conexao {

    private $sql, $user, $pass, $lista, $pdo;

    public function __construct($sql = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste',$user = 'root', $pass = '') {

        $this->sql  = $sql;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;

    }

    public function Conecta(){

        //Verifica se já está conectado
        if ($this->pdo) {
            return $this->pdo;
        }

        try {

            $this->pdo = new PDO($this->sql,$this->user,$this->pass);

        }catch(Exception $e) {

            var_dump($e);

        }

        return $this->pdo;    
    }
```

E não precisa chamar esta linha:

```
$testando->Conecta();
```

Já que está usando `Conecta` internamente na classe:

```
$testando = new Conexao;
$testando->getList();
```

Comment: deu certinho, muito obrigado, eu achava que o metodo try fazia o retorno de forma automatica, sem precisar mandar retornar algo

Comment: @OtavioFagundes recomendo que leia http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635